# Querying JsonLd with Sparql using Apache Jena

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena, json-ld

I am looking for Vice and Versa.

Is there a way I can query jsonld using Sparql?

If yes then please share any of the examples in Java ?

Comment: ehm, yes? Use Jena docs? I mean, JSON-LD is just a serialization format for RDF, Jena is an RDF framework, so load the JSON-LD data into Jena, then execute a SPARQL query.

Comment: I did that but my question is whether to convert it into model or dataset first ?  for now i have converted my jsonld to Model first and then set the model into Dataset .I did this thinking that incase if it is possible to that i get multiple model in future then i have model and dataset seperate .Do we need to parse the model or not that is my second question ?

Comment: a dataset is just a set of graphs. so your model must be represented by a graph URI. Regarding your second question, I do not understand. When you loaded the JSON-LD into a Jena model, it already has been parsed. I mean, that's the core operation. Parse data into their internal datastructures, which in the case of `Model` are `Statement` which represent the RDF triples.

Comment: Okay so you mean its the same whether i load my json ld into Model ,Dataset or DatasetGraph type ??And then Query with the sparql after quering i need to convert the response back to  readable json ,any leads would be appreciated

Comment: I am getting a response like this { "head": {
    "vars": [ "s" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      { 
        "s": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://domainname.ee/sampleClass/demoSample-desc.jsonId" }
      } ,
      { 
        "s": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://domainname.ee/sampleClass/demo.jsonld" }
      } 
    ]
  }
}

Comment: The response i want is count the vars and get only the value from the individual sample:
{ "head": {
    "vars": [ "sampleClass" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      { 
        "sample": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://domainname.ee/sampleClass/demoSample-desc.jsonId" }
      } ,
      { 
        "sample": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://domainname.ee/sampleClass/demo.jsonld" }
      } 
    ]
  }
}

Comment: I don't understand why you think anybody can help without sesing data, query and expected result. I mean, you just showed some SPARQL response in JSON format. So what can I say here?

Comment: Maybe it is an old question and user has found the answer. For anybody looking into this, this page lists the best pages to deal with JSON-LD across language frameworks. https://json-ld.org/